# Convert value of dictionary in a Dataframe to columns. Also add extra columns using the other values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame which initially looks like this

```
date        some_info
2020-01-01  [{'a': 1, 'hour': -1, 'data': 2}, {'a': 2, 'ho...
2020-01-02  [{'a': 1, 'hour': -1, 'data': 2}, {'a': 2, 'ho...
2020-01-03  [{'a': 1, 'hour': -1, 'data': 2}, {'a': 2, 'ho...
......
```

where some_info is a list of dictionary like

```
[{"a" : 1, "hour" : -1, "data":2},{"a" : 2, "hour" : 1, "data":2},{"a" : 3, "hour" : 4, "data":2},{"a" : 4, "hour" : 6, "data":2}]
```

how do i make *hour* as columns for a data frame with addition columns like -1_a+data, 1_a+data,1_a-data,1_a*data... for each hour. in a single row

```
Date      -1_a  1_a  4_a  6_a   6_a+data    

2020-01-01 1     2   3    4        6
2020-01-02 1     2   3    4        6
2020-01-03 1     2   3    4        6
```

I was able to achieve this using 2 for loops and consumes more time for large data.

Is there any better way to do it?

[EDIT]

Calcution for `-1_a+data` is for the date(row) at hour `-1` add `a` and `data` so here it would be `(a)1+ (data)2 = (-1_a+data) 3`

Comment: How do you calculate value like `-1_a+data`?

Comment: "1_a+data" indicates for the given date(row) add "a" value at "1" hour with "data" value at "1" hour

Comment: If you want help, edit the question with example calculation for the list of dictionary you already provided as example would greatly help other people to answer it and help you

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
date,some_info
2020-01-01,"[{""a"" : 1, ""hour"" : -1, ""data"":2},{""a"" : 2, ""hour"" : 1, ""data"":2},{""a"" : 3, ""hour"" : 4, ""data"":2},{""a"" : 4, ""hour"" : 6, ""data"":2}]"
2020-01-02,"[{""a"" : 1, ""hour"" : -1, ""data"":4},{""a"" : 2, ""hour"" : 1, ""data"":9},{""a"" : 3, ""hour"" : 4, ""data"":2},{""a"" : 4, ""hour"" : 6, ""data"":23}]"
2020-01-03,"[{""a"" : 1, ""hour"" : -1, ""data"":4},{""a"" : 2, ""hour"" : 1, ""data"":15},{""a"" : 3, ""hour"" : 4, ""data"":22},{""a"" : 4, ""hour"" : 6, ""data"":223}]"
```

Explode the `some_info` to rows, calculate value and key base on data, then pivot:

```
a['some_info'] = a['some_info'].apply(json.loads)

a = a.explode('some_info')

a['key'] = a['some_info'].apply(lambda x: str(x['hour']) + 'a+data')
a['value'] = a['some_info'].apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['data'])

a = a.loc[:, ['date', 'key', 'value']]
a = a.pivot_table(values='value', index=['date'], columns='key', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
date,-1a+data,1a+data,4a+data,6a+data
2020-01-01,3,4,5,6
2020-01-02,5,11,5,27
2020-01-03,5,17,25,227
```

Comment: How will I be able to perform other operations in the same DataFrame. ```-1_a-data```  ```-1_a*data``` ...  also just have ```-1_a```

Comment: Create multiple `dataframe`, change calculation and key at column `key` and `value` I created as example in my answer, than union them all back to a big dataframe,

Comment: A small edit, there are also operation which needs data of different hour slot ```-1_a_diff_1``` is difference of "a" value at hour "1" and "-1"

Comment: For the difference, dont explode them, do this instead: `a['value'] = a['some_info'].apply(lambda x: {j['hour']: j['a'] for j in x}).apply(lambda x: x[-1] - x[1])`